# How copy some message from one kafka topic to another from bash?

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

pls help

We have 2 kafka topic. I want copy 10 message from beginning from topic1 to topic2.

I`m try do it with *kafka-console-consumer* and *kafka-console-producer*

First i save 10 message from topic1 to some directory:

```
for (( i=1; i<=10; i++ )); do bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 1.1.2.3:9092 --group CONSUMER1 --topic TOPIC1 --max-messages 1 > /tmp/_topic/$i.msg; done;
```

then i try with kafka-console-producer send it to topic2:

```
for (( i=1; i<=10; i++ )); do  bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 1.1.2.4:9092 --topic TOPIC2 < /tmp/_topic/$i.msg; done;
```

And i got error - my service Can't deserialize data. 
My question is:

1. does my solution will work ?
2. Why i can reciev this error ?
3. What is best way to copy message from one topic to another once ?

UPD:
How i`m solve this problem (thanks: Robin Moffatt):
I using kafka-mirror and this jar :
https://github.com/opencore/mirrormaker_topic_rename
with this i can copy message from one topic kafka to another on one cluster

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with [`kafkacat`](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat):

```
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -C -t source-topic -K: -e -o beginning -c10 | \
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -P -t target-topic -K:
```

- `|` redirects the output of the first kafkacat (which is a `-C` consumer) into the input of the second kafkacat (which is a `-P` producer)
- `-c10` means just consume 10 messages
- `-o beginning` means start at the beginning of the topic.

Note that this won't work if you've got binary data (e.g. Avro). To properly do this use something like Replicator or MirrorMaker2 and a ByteArrayConverter.

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2019/09/29/copying-data-between-kafka-clusters-with-kafkacat/

Comment: thanks for answer. As i understand Mirror maker can only mirror one topic to same topic on another cluster( with same name and etc.), but i need copy message from topic1 to topic2 on one cluster.
And we use avro :(

Comment: I've not used it, but I don't see why you can't give your source and target brokers as the same in MirrorMaker2. Because it's built on Kafka Connect you should be able to use the RegExRouter Single Message Transform (SMT) to route the topic from `topic1` to `topic2`

Comment: This was useful but I had problems with the delimiter. I was trying to use characters as delimiters which are not supported. This is not documented, but kafkacat today only accepts delimiters which are single-byte (i.e. contained within the first 127 ascii chars). The fix has been open for 3 years here: https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/pull/150

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in doing this for **binary** kafka messages, I wrote [a simple tool (`kpipe`)](https://github.com/cmantas/kpipe) to do that. Hope it helps someone